# How to say "I have an extra phone" using the word "spare"?

Tags: vocabulary

One of my friend was in need of emergency phone as he lost his, though i told him that "I have an extra phone and he can use it if he want" but later I was trying to figure out what are the different ways to say that then I came up with this " I have one phone on spare" but it sounds awkward and off rules. Please suggest me how can I use it in the mentioned context. Thanks.

Comment: "I have a spare phone" or "I can spare you a phone" are fine.

Comment: Please use capital letters  ***I*** ( not i ) when referring to yourself.

Answer (score 2):

[Spare](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spare) as an adjective means ***extra***.  Here are a few usage examples:

> - If something is spare, it is ​available to use because it is ​extra:
>
>   - *a spare ​key/​tyre*
>   - *spare ​sheets and ​blankets*
>   - *Do you have a spare ​pen?*
>   - *We have a spare ​room if you ​want to ​stay ​overnight with us.*
>   - *Could I have a word with you when you have a spare ​moment/​minute?*
> - (UK informal) "Do you ​want this ​cake?" "Yes, if it's going spare"

(Cambridge Dictionary)

- I have a  spare phone I can lend you

Answer (score 0):

You may say : 
I have a phone that I can spare